# How to update a Deal custom field in Pipedrive API?

Tags: pipedrive-api

I have a list of custom fields for a Deals in Pipedrive. (Located here https://your-instance.pipedrive.com/settings/fields?type=DEAL)

Each custom field has a custom `API Key` which looks like this `a56aff894af47285d3bbcd67fe06ee5143fb1123`

I try to update these fields in a Deal in bulk.

According to the `Update a deal` documentation https://developers.pipedrive.com/docs/api/v1/#!/Deals/put_deals_id there is no information about these custom fields.

The question is how to update custom field value in a certain Deal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can send custom field key - value pairs just in the request body.

According to [this example](https://pipedrive.readme.io/docs/updating-custom-field-value):

```
// Pipedrive API token
$api_token = '659c9fddb16335e48cc67114694b52074e812';

// Custom field key value pairs
$data = array(
  'dcf558aac1ae4e8c4f849ba5e668430d8df9be12' => 'Custom field value'
);

// Deal ID
$deal_id = 260;

// URL for updating a Deal
$url = 'https://your-instance.pipedrive.com/api/v1/deals/' . $deal_id . '?api_token=' . $api_token;

// Prepare CURL Request
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```